# How to combine many records value into one record

Tags: make.com, integromat-apps

As you can see from the below picture I was able to combine two deals (blocked red) but the output should have one result instead of two. If anyone has any solutions on this please advise.

[image]

The red blocked component has more than one record, each record has an amount, the sum of all record amount must be shown in a single row.

```
record1: Amount:100
record2: Amount:200
record3: Amount:500
```

Merge of all records is following

```
record: Amount:800
```

Is it possible to merge many rows into a single row in integromat?

Comment: Hi, Did you get this to work. If not can you share me the screenshot of the aggregator?

Comment: @Runcorn, no I still stuck on the issue, you may help me to merge many column records and update the specific one record.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your screenshot you aggregate an incorrect module. `Source module` in your aggregator has to be set to a module that generates multiple modules, in your case, it is module 10.

You aggregate module 14 that generates for every input module a single output module, there is nothing to aggregate. Module 10 returns for a single input 2 bundles.

```
Your case:
       /---[6]---([14]---[11 aggregator])---
---[10]                                       multiple output bundles
       \---[6]---([14]---[11 aggregator])---


Solution:
        /---[6]---[14]---\
---([10]                  [11 aggregator])--- single output bundle
        \---[6]---[14]---/
```

Your scenario has to look like this (`Aggregator: Source module` = module no.10):
[image]

Comment: I tried your solution but get the same result, is it possible to create one scenario on integromat and share it with me, may be it will be very helpful!

Comment: I've updated my answer and provided a screenshot with the correct solution. I hope it helps.